# How to call specific action on drop down selected change event in rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have on select_tag on my page and this drop down have language collection. now i want to change all the messages according to language selected in the drop down. For that i need to call action on the selection change. So how i will call the same.

Thanks,
Lalit

Comment: Do you want to call same action for all selection?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the drop down within a form, when the drop down changes use javascript to submit the form.